# When using JOIN statement reader does not work

Tags: mysql, c, join

**Preface:**
I have to read 3 tables by scanning the first table. In first table (ProdBiscuit) I have the production quantity and some other datas in two others(ProdMacaron, StockData) i have the used quantity and some other datas. I realised this [code](http://turcguide.com/stack/3tables.txt). This methode are working but takes about 1 minutes for checking all (i'am working with an external server not at localhost).

**HOPE:** 
I think the join statement in MYSQL must be a solution for speeding this. I wrote this [methode](http://turcguide.com/stack/onemethode.txt) but in line where there is while(reader.read()) it jumps to the end of the function without giving any error. What can be the problem?

PS:I'am using InnoDB with my database, c#2008

Comment: Questions concerning code you have written must contain a [short self-contained correct example](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not joining the three tables on anything. That might be a start. Are there any IDs in any of the other tables that reference ProdBiscuit's `ID` column or something?

Also, just FYI... if you're using `using` wrappers for your SQL transactions, you don't need to write `conn.Open()`. The `using` will handle the connection open/close for you.

Comment: Just now I noticed that. I've not data in one table and 3 rows of data on other JOINED table after discarding empty table I've got three rows of data. I'am still searching :(. In ProdBiscuit there are 29 rows StockData 3 rows null ProdMacaron (I suppressed this for testing)

Comment: Yeah, the amount of data is not what I matters here. It's more about the relation between each table. If you could search your schema, we could probably help you better.

Comment: Thanks very much for the idea. I changed my InnoDB tables it works much faster now +1